# Can I download raw data from Google Analytics for another processing?

Tags: google-analytics

I had disabled Apache log on my web so I have only data for a few last days. On the other hand Google Analytics tracks my web for months. So I'm interested if it is possible to get raw data from Google Analytics. I'm particularly interested in: visitor IP + my web URL address.

Comment: Do you mean something other than what's already provided by the [export function](https://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57161)? As long as you can generate a report that shows what you're after, you should be able to export it. It's highly unlikely they're ever going to hand over the actual raw information used to generate the GA reports.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the GA API...

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/

Good luck =)